# configure .htaccess to allow subdomain but not direct access

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two subdomains. (test1.domain.com and test2.domain.com) And I want to deny the direct access to the test1.domain.de. Only if you come from test2.domain.de it should be allowed. Unfortunately have not found a solution. Can someone help? Technical note: apache version 2.4.
I have tried with, but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!test2.domain.com" [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

Comment: And "it's not working" means what _exactly_ ? What happens if you make a test request? And what does your http server's error log file contain? Have you enabled the interpretation of such distributed configuration files (".htaccess") _at all_ ? How? And if, have you tried writing an explicit syntax error inside while monitoring the error log file to verify that the rule _really_ is getting applied?

Comment: Ich meine damit, dass man es trotzdem auf die Seite direkt zugreifen kann. I habe versucht mit .htaccess den ganzen Zugriff verweigern. Und es hat auch funktioniert. Aus dem Log kann ich leider keine relevaten Informationen ableiten

Comment: Entschuldige bitte, das ist ein englisch-sprachiges Forum hier ...

Comment: Have a try like that: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^test2\.domain\.com$ [NC]`

Comment: sorry guys for the late reply but i solved it. was a bug in regex

Comment: ```RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com\/$ [NC]```